# beginner trying to debug python code to call FCC API on net neutrality comments

Tags: python, json

below is some code courtesy of Jeffrey Fossett https://github.com/Fossj117/fossj117.github.io/blob/master/_code/2017-05-13-fcc-filings/final/fcc_filings_with_public_api.py

I just set up my python environment and am trying to run this code (I have an API key inserted into the code in my environment)

'''
Quick script for scraping FCC filings about docket 17-108 with Python using the 
FCC's public API https://www.fcc.gov/ecfs/public-api-docs.html
Note: 
'''

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd

def get_filings(endpoint, offset, n_records, proceeding, api_key): 
''' 
Gets FCC filings about given proceeding from endpoint, starting 
at offset and collecting n_records (breaks if n_records too large)
'''

print "Trying to get filings {} to {}...".format(str(offset), str(offset + n_records))

payload = {'limit':n_records, 'proceedings.name': proceeding, 'offset':offset, 'api_key': api_key, "sort": "date_submission,ASC"}

r = requests.get(endpoint, params = payload)
filings = r.json()['filings']

print "...got {}, returned {} filings".format(r.reason, len(filings))

return filings


def clean_data(filings): 
''' 
Clean up the raw scraped data for analysis
'''

df = pd.DataFrame(filings)

df_filtered = df[['id_submission', 'contact_email', 'date_submission', 'date_received', 'date_disseminated','text_data', 'addressentity']]

# Extract geo data 
df_filtered['city'] = df_filtered.addressentity.apply(lambda x: x['city'] if 'city' in x.keys() else None)
df_filtered['state'] = df_filtered.addressentity.apply(lambda x: x['state'] if 'state' in x.keys() else None)
df_filtered['zip_code'] = df_filtered.addressentity.apply(lambda x: x['zip_code'] if 'zip_code' in x.keys() else None)

df_clean = df_filtered.drop(['addressentity'], axis = 1)

return df_clean

if __name__ == '__main__': 

# static params
PROCEEDING = '17-108'
ENDPOINT = 'https://publicapi.fcc.gov/ecfs/filings'

API_KEY = "" # Your API Key Here 

# initialize
OFFSET = 0
N_RECORDS = 10000 # larger than this seems to break the API

filings = []

# Main Loop
while True: 

    new_filings = get_filings(ENDPOINT, OFFSET, N_RECORDS, PROCEEDING, API_KEY)

    if new_filings: 

        filings += new_filings
        OFFSET += N_RECORDS

    else: 

        break 

# clean the data up & write it to a file for analysis
df_clean = clean_data(filings)
df_clean.to_csv('raw_data_pub_api_sorted_5_14_2AM.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

File "query.py", line 16
    print "Trying to get filings {} to {}...".format(str(offset), str(offset + n_records))
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I'm guessing there's a syntax error either in the print command or else in the static param I'm calling? (since that's where it breaks). That said I'm kind of at a loss for what it is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did your count your parens? That's the problem 90% of the time. Did not actually read your code.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? `python --version`

Comment: Please correct the indentation.  Cannot reproduce: executing that line by itself with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to wrap your print statements in parentheses, like so:

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd

def get_filings(endpoint, offset, n_records, proceeding, api_key): 
    ''' 
    Gets FCC filings about given proceeding from endpoint, starting 
    at offset and collecting n_records (breaks if n_records too large)
    '''

    print("Trying to get filings {} to {}...".format(str(offset), str(offset + n_records)))

    payload = {'limit':n_records, 'proceedings.name': proceeding, 'offset':offset, 'api_key': api_key, "sort": "date_submission,ASC"}

    r = requests.get(endpoint, params = payload)
    filings = r.json()['filings']

    print("...got {}, returned {} filings".format(r.reason, len(filings)))

    return filings


def clean_data(filings): 
    ''' 
    Clean up the raw scraped data for analysis
    '''

    df = pd.DataFrame(filings)

    df_filtered = df[['id_submission', 'contact_email', 'date_submission', 'date_received', 'date_disseminated','text_data', 'addressentity']]

    # Extract geo data 
    df_filtered['city'] = df_filtered.addressentity.apply(lambda x: x['city'] if 'city' in x.keys() else None)
    df_filtered['state'] = df_filtered.addressentity.apply(lambda x: x['state'] if 'state' in x.keys() else None)
    df_filtered['zip_code'] = df_filtered.addressentity.apply(lambda x: x['zip_code'] if 'zip_code' in x.keys() else None)

    df_clean = df_filtered.drop(['addressentity'], axis = 1)

    return df_clean

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    # static params
    PROCEEDING = '17-108'
    ENDPOINT = 'https://publicapi.fcc.gov/ecfs/filings'

    API_KEY = "rVFHpkCgR2oigr9vQmJREnrSUVtaJC1NIiMgYL8S" # Your API Key Here 

    # initialize
    OFFSET = 0
    N_RECORDS = 10000 # larger than this seems to break the API

    filings = []

    # Main Loop
    while True: 

        new_filings = get_filings(ENDPOINT, OFFSET, N_RECORDS, PROCEEDING, API_KEY)

        if new_filings: 
            filings += new_filings
            OFFSET += N_RECORDS
        else: 
            break 

    # clean the data up & write it to a file for analysis
    df_clean = clean_data(filings)
    df_clean.to_csv('raw_data_pub_api_sorted_5_14_2AM.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

this worked for me, though my computer ran out of memory after getting 160K filings :)

Answer (score 1):

What version of python are you using?
In python3 use:

`print("whatever you wanna print")`
 instead of 

`print "whatever you wanna print"`